# Custom feed VS view

Tags: views, feeds

I need to view data from external sources - real time is not mission critical. Updated a few times per day is acceptable.

What is easier in terms of development complexity:

1. Implementing a Views plugin to connect to third party data and return it in a fashion acceptable by Views modules?
2. Implement a Feeds importer that knows how to connect to third party sources and dump into required content types?

Can you give a high level break down of interfaces required to implement each and which (in your own experience) is less time consuming or easier to implement?

Thanks

Comment: What are your external sources? Is it an XML file? Are you crawling from pages? Whats the data? More info required.

Comment: Mysql...I realize now it would make note sense to export as CSV then import using feeds